# Best way to program a plugin for multiple browsers

Tags: cross-browser, plugins

i was wondering what would be the best way to code a browser plugin that is for multiple browsers.

Due to the fact that each browser uses other ways of implementing plugins there should be a library or something with the basic functionality and a wrapper for each browser. So, to be more precise, with which language the library should be programmed?

The plugin shall implement functions like: Retrieving files from another server (via SSH) and sound playback.

Regards
macs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about common denominators when you're doing cross-platform stuff. You need to pick the things that you know will work on all your targets. This will require some research on your part. I know this answer is a bit vague, but you don't state exactly which list of browsers you wish to support. Is it just Firefox, IE, and Safari? Opera as well? These are things you have to think about.

That said, your best bet is to pick a language that is supported by each browser you wish to target.

Comment: Well, let's say i want to support as many browsers as possible, at least the most common ones: Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, Google Chrome, Konqueror, ...

I know that there is NPAPI, but that won't work on IE, won't it?

Comment: AFAIK even major plugin developers such as Adobe have NPAPI and IE versions.